# Generated Windows 10 Wim from Hyper-V has default playback device set to headphones

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image, hyper-v, wim

I have generated a WIM from a Hyper-V VM. 
After deploying the WIM I noticed the default playback device is set to 'headphones'.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening? Is there anything I can do in Hyper-V to help or do I need to run some sort of script after deploying the image?

Comment: You can apply the .wim to a partition, boot to it change the default playback device, then use DISM to create a new .wim image

Comment: What version of hyper-v are you running. I have created dozens of .wim's for all OSes ranging from XP, to Win 10 and server 2008 through 2016 on hyper-v, VMware, and virtual box. I have never seen this issue. Are you sure you are sysprepping your image with the /generalize switch before imaging it and reinstalling the proper drivers after deployment?

Comment: @Appleoddity Hyper-v on Windows 10. Yes we sysprep with generalize and the drivers are installed after deployment.

Comment: @Ramhound would this not increase the sysprep count?

Comment: @Appleoddity With regards to the drivers..what I did was I went to model-specific machine and exported all the drivers. I did notice there was a driver for the TV/screen we use which I removed from the set of drivers before re-importing them in the WIM as it was specific to the make of the TV/Screen. Could this be it? If I import this driver in the WIM and another make of TV/Screen is used when deploying the image, wont it be ignored and I'll have the same issue as before?

Comment: @JD I haven't done it this way. Having extra drivers should not affect anything. All my deployments are universal, I don't import drivers in to the wim and I think you should try this for troubleshooting. Compare behavior both before and after installing the drivers. For me, I use MDT for deployments and maintain a database of drivers for all possible hardware. MDT injects the specific drivers after applying the wim and I've never seen this issue. If you are using a single model you might be better off imaging from the machine and utilizing 'persistalldeviceinstalls' in unattend.

Comment: Btw, I usually use a generation 1 VM and I don't tweak any integration settings. So maybe you've got something tweaked in Hyper-v also that is causing this issue on the resulting .wim. MDT can deploy the same .wim universally in MBR or UEFI mode as needed so I stick with generation 1.

Comment: @Appleoddity. Initially the imaging process was done outside of Hyper-v (Generation 2) and I remember the same issue then. So it was something that existed before Hyper-V. I am not to familiar with the initial setup (unattend etc) so I'll check the unattend file if there is something in there that maybe causing the issue. Thank you so much for the help. Hopefully I'll get it resolved.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Just installed a windows 10 image (did not put any of our custom software on the WIM or injected any drivers) and found that lots of drivers were missing. I checked the sound tab (control panel) and found that headphones was the default device but as the drivers were not installed there were a number of 'Intel Display Audio' disabled entries. After around 10 minutes once windows had installed the drivers, I saw 'E430i-C2 (Intel Display Audio) (for my VIZIO display) but it was enabled for the Default Communication device. So should I be setting a value in the autoattend?

Comment: @JD - Unfortunately, I'm not sure. You are doing good troubleshooting. I'm convinced it centers around the driver installation of this "alternative" audio device. I just did the same process this weekend and deployed 20 systems with no issues. Due to the nature of this issue, if you are deploying to similar hardware, I would create the image on the machine with the proper drivers and configured properly. Later, if your unattend contains the `persistalldeviceinstalls` option it should work after deployment. MDT is a worthy investment if you are doing a lot of deployments.